# Apply fadein effect to tooltip?

Tags: jquery

I have this code, which shows the tooltip within a box with the id of "tooltip-container" - currently it just pops in...how can I make it fade nicely and fade out on roll-off?

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    var tooltipId = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('#tooltip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).show();
        $('#tooltip-container').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
    }, function(){
        $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `.show()` use `.fadeIn(timeInMS)`
Same for `.fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a time period in your show() and hide() methods...

```
.show(1000); // takes 1 second to fade in
.hide(1000); // takes 1 second to fade out
```